Compare and swap with relaxed atomics
void foo(atomic<int> &x) {
    int i = 0;
    bool success = x.compare_exchange_strong(i, i + 2, memory_order_relaxed, memory_order_relaxed);
    assert(!success);
}

void bar(atomic<int> &x) {
    x.store(1, memory_order_relaxed);
}

int main() {
    atomic<int> x = 0;
    auto bar_thread = thread(bar, std::ref(x));
    sleep(1);
    auto foo_thread = thread(foo, std::ref(x));
    sleep(1);
    foo_thread.join();
    bar_thread.join();
}

I think any thread interleaving is possible even with the sleep but can we assume that the machine runs bar to completion before foo for the purpose of this example.
In this example, can I expect that the assert to never fail? My understanding here is that even though x.store(1, memory_order_relaxed) operation is atomic, its visibility may not be immediate to other threads, unless it was paired with acquire-release or sequential consistency.
I passed memory_order_relaxed to the failure argument to compare exchange, so as far as I know it could read the original value of 0. But the assert never gets triggered (which I understand now that it doesn't mean much).
Is it that compare_exchange_strong will always in the end synchronize with the last write, regardless of the memory orders passed in? I assume x's initial value is read with memory_order_relaxed, and only if it's equal to expected, that it would do a more expensive operation that does compare and swap with x?

memory_order_relaxed only refers to how the atomic instruction may be reordered with regard to surrounding instructions - but it can't result in being reordered before any explicit aquire / after any release operations, nor beyond any explicit synchronization points such as a thread join.

I didn't know that thread join is a synchronization point, thank you. I'll replace it with sleep since that wasn't my intention

Are you running this on x86 btw? It doesn't really have a relaxed semantics at all (except for certain special cases), so testing on x86 won't show any of the interesting behavior even when it is allowed, beyond the usual level of "testing cannot show the absence of bugs, only their presence"

yep, I am using x86

You seem to assume that bar is guaranteed to execute first, and set x==1. But nothing in the code prevents foo from starting first, while x is still zero, and before the bar thread even spins up. This is before we even get into the funny business with memory order - it can happen even if you use seq_cst order throughout. Your sleep calls make this less likely (and thus more difficult to reproduce, giving you a false sense of security), but sleep is not a synchronization mechanism.

Even if the store to x used release or sequentially consistent memory ordering, it's still the case that it may not be visible to another thread because there is no synchronization between them.
When a release store S performed by thread 1 synchronizes with an acquire load L performed by thread 2, then operations in thread 2 after L will see all side effects performed by operations in thread 1 before S. But this doesn't apply to the store S itself, because that would be circular. S only synchronizes with L in the first place if L happens to read the value that was stored by S... so the synchronization can't make S itself visible to L, because L seeing the side effect S is a condition precedent to the synchronization happening in the first place.
In practice, if a second really passes between the store in bar and the load in foo, then the former should have become visible to the latter on any realistic implementation.
But, although it's unlikely to happen, it's theoretically possible that the thread that executes bar just doesn't get scheduled until after the load in foo has already happened, in which case obviously the store won't be visible, because it hasn't happened yet. And it's also theoretically possible that the compiler could "optimize" your code by deciding that the CAS always succeeds, since that's one of the possible executions according to the rules of the abstract machine. (And presumably, in that case, the compiler would also optimize out x entirely since no one else is reading its value.)
